# Codenameone UIDesigner out of sync with file

Tags: eclipse, git, file, synchronization, codenameone

I'm developing a Codenameone app using Eclipse, Git and Bitbucket.

I'm doing work on two computers, one at my home office and one laptop when I'm on the go.  Therefore I use Git and Bitbucket to ensure that my files are kept in sync across both computers.

I've run into a strange issue with the UIDesigner on my laptop.  It seems that it has cached an old version of the .res-file and when I open the file with the UIDesigner I see old design in it.  My changes from the other computer are not visible in the designer.  I have tried to copy the file to a new filename and open that new file and then I see the changes, so therefore I suspect some caching of the file contents are going on.

Is there a way to disable the caching (at least temporarily) and ensure that the UIDesigner actually reads the file contents from disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "simple" solution is to commit the res directory or turn off the File->XML Team Mode in the designer.

The res file is a binary file which makes working with versioning systems hard. That's why we effectively "shadow" it using the res directory where its content is "exploded" as XML and data files to prevent conflicts.

So if you have 2 people on the team who modified the res file you can just pick any version in the merge but merge the res folder properly. Then when you open the designer and save the res folder will be preferred and as you save the binary res file will be recreated.

If you are working on the project alone you can just turn off team mode to avoid the noise of additional files.